# VirtualBox Ubuntu 14 guest running on win7 host has no Internet access with Bridged Adapter

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, windows-7, virtualbox

My VM Linux ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on Win 7 host lost Internet access while running on Bridged Adapter. I do not know the precise event that this happened after - therefore it is hard for me to troubleshoot. So I'm here for some help :)

**A couple of points:**

- It worked before - not sure what changed though. One thing might be related: I installed VMware player on the same host as well (but it is shut down);
- Attaching the VM to NAT based Internet connection works fine;
- I tried playing around with some of the settings in VirtualBox manager when the problem arose;
- I tried disabling the VMware services (like DHCP service, NAT service, etc.) - that did not help.

I have attached some screen-shots that might be helpful. Thank you for your input! I would really appreciate not only the solution but the thinking process of how to troubleshoot it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, it worked out-of-the-box but suddenly stopped. Perhaps due to installation of Guest Additions, not sure. Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes - in my case I have both VM virtualbox and VMware player installed in my machine. The connetions somehow got mixed up even when I was running only one of those applications. Going to VMware > Virtual Machine settings for your VM > Network adapter > Configure adapters and try swithing around the adapters if you have the same set up as I had. If not, please add a question to stack overflow - I'm sure you and someone else will benefit from it :)

Comment: Actually my case was a bit different, I didn't work even with NAT option. I didn't know what really happened, the cheaper options was to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch once again and it was working fine since then. This time I was wiser and made a snapshot in Virtualbox after installation :) It didn't seem to be a guest additions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it - in my case I have both VM virtualbox and VMware player installed in my machine. The connetions somehow got mixed up even when I was running only one of those applications.

Going to VMware Player > Virtual Machine settings for your VM > Network adapter > Configure adapters and try swithing around the adapters if you have the same set up as I had. It might be helpfull to restart the VirtualBox VM after you do some switching in VMWare player (but I'm not sure it is necessary);

Also, I think the internet connection was succesfully established on virtualbox VM once I turned on the VMWare VM - but I'm not sure 100% about it.

Please add comments if you had similar issue and how you resolved it - I think this would save countless nerve cells aroud the world :)

Comment: I have the similar problem. In the past, Internet on my VM (virtualbox, ubuntu 14.04) worked fine. But two days ago I installed vmware with Ubuntu. Now I have no internet on Ubuntu (virtualbox). I try switch off nat in vmware, but It have no any success.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, if your NAT mode network is working well then I assume there is nothing wrong with your virtual box installation. While the NAT mode doesn't require much additional setting beside set the virtual machine to use DHCP, the bridged adapter mode need some additional configuration. Because it's basically to simulate that your virtual machine has it's own LAN cable and plug it into the switch or router by "riding" your real connection (whether it is wired or wireless). So, to make it work please configure your Ubuntu's wired connection to use the same configuration as your host computer/windows (but of course with different IP address).
Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VMs in bridged network options, do the following changes in the VMware network. Open Virtual network editor on VMware.

[image: wmware network editor]

click on changes setting at the bottom. It will as you for admin permissions. click yes. now you will be able to see new connection in the list(possibly VMnet0) and able to edit the network settings.

[image]

select Bridge from option and click on Automatic settings. Unckeck all the other network options except the computer adapter. save the settings and restart VMs.

[image]